# Vim, coffeescript and windows (sadly)

Tags: vim, coffeescript

What is the best way of getting coffeescript to compile into javascript when using VIM on windows?

Comment: you're looking for some way to do it without leaving vim?

Comment: I have no idea what tools are available on windows, but I'd expect `make` involved here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using something like [Live Reload](http://livereload.com/) to watch your coffeescript for changes.

If you're looking for a pure vim solution, you can set `makeprg` for coffeescript files.  Add this to your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.coffee setlocal makeprg=coffee\ -c\ %
```

Then if you run `:make` while in a .coffee file, the current file will be compiled.